# Simulating TCP connection error for health-check

Tags: tcp, kong, health-check

I'm working on configuring health-check for upstream services using kong gateway, I want to simulate having a upstream service where I can make it periodically serve traffic over a port and then periodically give TCP connection error,  so that I can verify the state of service is switched between healthy and unhealthy.

Any help and lead is appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to test in local, with containers, with different servers ? Just start a basic http  like caddy, python http server or anything else

Comment: If I have to test this on AWS ECS and EC2?

Comment: Why not shutting down the  EC2 or ECS to simulate TCP connection error ?

Comment: I did try this but I'm getting ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT, but I need TCP connection error where packets are dropped during handshake.(SYN)

Answer (score 0):

You can use iptables to drop any input packet for a specific port. A script can be written to set or unset the iptable rule as needed.

Here is an example of how to use iptables to drop packets:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8000 -j DROP
```

In this command, 8000 is the port of your service. Be sure to replace 8000 with the actual port number your service uses.